# Objectify and relations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm trying to implement a simple GAE service. Particularry I have the Student entity and Category entity. To each Student can be associated one or more Categories. How can I create this relationship using Objectify? THanks

Edit: This is my code. Is It valid?

```
@Entity
public class Studente {
    static long nextID = 17;

    public static Key<Studente> key(long id) {
        return Key.create(Studente.class, id);
    }

    List<Key<Categoria>> categorie; 

    public Studente() {}

    @Id  Long id;
    @Index String nome;
    @Index String cognome;
    @Index String username;
    @Index String password;

    public Studente(String nome, String cognome, String username, String password) {
        this.nome=nome;
        this.cognome=cognome;
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        categorie = new ArrayList<Key<Categoria>>();
    }

    public static long getNextID() {
        return nextID;
    }

    public static void setNextID(long nextID) {
        Studente.nextID = nextID;
    }

    public List<Key<Categoria>> getCategorie() {
        return categorie;
    }

    public void setCategorie(List<Key<Categoria>> categorie) {
        this.categorie = categorie;
    }

    public void addCategoria(Key<Categoria> k ){
        categorie.add(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having a third entity with indexed references to both entities. That way, you could easily query for every student in a category, or for every category of a student.

```
@Entity
public class Student { /*...*/ }

@Entity
public class Category { /*...*/ }

@Entity
public class StudentCategory {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Index
    private Ref<Student> student;

    @Index
    private Ref<Category> category;

    /*...*/
}
```

We have a similar setup in our GAE applications, and it has served us well.

[See documentation of `Ref<?>`](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Ref%3C?%3E_s).

Comment: in the meantime of answers I did a sample working code. Can You check it in my question?

Comment: Your solution should work, but it is not very convenient. `Ref` is more convenient than `Key` (see the documentation I linked). Also, without having an `@Index` annotation on your list, you will not be able to query for students having a certain category. You will only be able to tell what categories a distinct student has. Leaving all that aside, your solution should work, yes.

Comment: You could do the same without intermediary `StudentCategory` entity, by using list of references in each `Student` and `Category`. This would save you extra code and cost.

Comment: @PeterKnego: That way, you would risk inconsistent data. A student could have a reference to the category, but the category could lack the reference to the student. If avoiding that risk altogether means having a little extra code and cost, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Jan As I see it your code has the same problem, if developer in the code somehow "forgets" to update entities. This can be simply solved by having a well-tested utility function that creates the relation.

Comment: @PeterKnego Actually, no, my code does not have the same problem. You will always have a consistent state. It is **physically impossible** for a student to be in a category, but the category not knowing the student.

Answer (score 1):

Create a muti-valued indexed field in `Student` that holds all `Category` IDs (or Keys):

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    public Long id;  // auto-generated Id of the Category

}

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    public Long id;  // auto-generated Id of the Student

    @Index
    public List<Long> categories;  // put Category Ids into this list
}
```

Indexed fields can be used in query filters, so you will be able to search for students that belong to certain category.

Comment: in the meantime of answers I did a sample working code. Can You check it in my question?